# Cómo seleccionar el DOM con Jquery apartir de dos arreglos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día amigos, tengo el siguiente código

```js
  fechaEventoP = [];
        /* Obtengo las tablas de los eventos */
        var campos = $("#fechas").find('table');
       /* Creo el arreglo con las claves*/

        var columnas= ["Numero_fechas","Horario","Fecha_completa","Fecha_inicio","Hora_inicio","Fecha_fin","Hora_fin","Tiempo_celebracion"];
    
       /* Iteramos sobre as filas del tbody*/
         for (var a = 0; a < campos.length; a++) {
        var obj1={};/* auxiliar*/
         for (var b = 0;b < columnas.length;b++) 

          // Obtenemos las claves         obtenemos los valores de los parrafos
            obj1[columnas[b]] =  campos[a].getElementsByTagName("p")[b].innerHTML;

        fechaEventoP.push(obj1);/* Añadimos al Array Principal*/

        }
```

Lo que hace es iterar una tabla y convertirla en un arreglo de objetos.

La idea es poder hacer esta parte, pero con jquery

```js
campos[a].getElementsByTagName("p")[b].innerHTML;
```

¿Alguén sabe cómo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo más simple con [ES6](http://es6-features.org/)

```
const columns = [...document.querySelectorAll('#fechas thead th')];

const rows = [...document.querySelectorAll('#fechas tbody tr')];

const items = rows.map(row => {
    const paragraphs = row.getElementsByTagName('p');
    const item = {};
    columns.forEach((column, i) => item[column] = paragraphs[i].innerHTML);
    return item;
});

console.log(items);
```